# How to filter object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to filter the object `value` from `desc` based on the `main`.

Is there any possible way i can get value `qwer` and save  into variable. As main contain `3` so i want to fetch the desc object value `qwer` in Reactjs

```js
const data = {
  main: "3",
  desc: [
    {
      id: "1",
      value: "xyz"
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      value: "abc"
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      value: "qwer"
    },
    {
      id: "4",
      value: "cwer"
    }
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `id` in `desc` array is unique, you could use `find` (doc for [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find))

```js
const data = {
  main: '3',
  desc: [
    {
      id: '1',
      value: 'xyz'
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      value: 'abc'
    },
    {
      id: '3',
      value: 'qwer'
    },
    {
      id: '4',
      value: 'cwer'
    }
  ]
}

const res = data.desc.find(d => d.id === data.main)

console.log(res.value)
```